# Using not in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I make this query to use `Not in` condition not in the whole table but limit the condition for each customer

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Service.Service_ID
    ,dbo.Service.Service_RNO
    ,dbo.Customer.Cust_Name
    ,dbo.Service.Agrement_ID
    ,dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
    ,dbo.Service.Service_Date
    ,dbo.Service.Next_Service
FROM
    dbo.Service
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Customer ON dbo.Service.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
WHERE 
    Next_Service BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
    AND Next_Service NOT IN (SELECT Service_Date from Service)
ORDER BY 
    Next_Service
```

For example let's say I have this data

```
Service_ID  Service_RNO Cust_Name   Agrement_ID Cust_ID Service_Date    Next_Service
1                 1       customer1    35         15     2016-01-01     2016-01-31
2                 2       customer1    35         15     2016-01-31     2016-03-2
3                 3       customer2    12         21     2016-01-31     2016-03-2
```

out put of this query will be empty since the next service is existed in the `service_date`

The query should give customer 2 rows of data since `Next_Service` not existed in `service_date` for that customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question:

```
SELECT  dbo.Service.Service_ID, 
        dbo.Service.Service_RNO, 
        dbo.Customer.Cust_Name,
        dbo.Service.Agrement_ID,
        dbo.Customer.Cust_ID,
        dbo.Service.Service_Date,
        dbo.Service.Next_Service 
FROM dbo.Service 
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer ON dbo.Service.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID 
WHERE  Next_Service between '2016-01-01' and '2016-02-01' 
AND    Next_Service not in (
          SELECT Service_Date 
          FROM Service s
          WHERE s.Cust_ID = dbo.Customer.Cust_ID
) 
ORDER BY Next_Service
```